# milliseconds between a specified date and convert to date format in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

convert milliseconds between a specified date and to date format in js

```
$.each(item,function(index,a){
var date=1416249000000;
Date date1=new Date(date);
htmlTable += '<td>'+date1+'</td>';
});
```

this causes error

how to parse this to date format inside jquery

**edit**

my question  the date value doesn't contain 'l' at last sorry it's my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
var time = 1322018752992;
var date = new Date(time); //date is full date string. ie, Wed Nov 23 2011 09:...

//Now if you want to get the formatted date
var year = date.getFullYear(),
    month = (date.getMonth() + 1),
    day = date.getDate();
if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

var properlyFormatted = year + "-" + month +  "-" + day;
alert(properlyFormatted);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable in JavaScript, you don't use the variables type.
So even if it is a date object (or any other type of object or primitive), you use the `var` keyword.

```
var date = 1322018752992;
var date1 = new Date(date);
```

---

*Earlier answer before question was edited:*
There is an `l` at the end of your number (the letter L in lowercase).
This would, in a language with multiple type of number structures, indicate that it is a long.
But JavaScript does not have multiple number types, only `number`, and a `number` is a `64b` floating point value.
So, if you remove the `l`, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid JavaScript, it appears to be Java, there is no typing like Java, only [duck typinng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), you declare everything as var. I suggest you search for 'javascript introduction', there are many good tutorials out there which will help you master the basics.

```
Date date1=new Date(date);
```

I think you meant

```
var date1 = new Date(date);
```

Additionally if you need to format dates, use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), this provides similar functionality to Java's Jodatime and core libraries like SimpleDataFormat, which JavaScript lacks.